# join problem on image background across two pages

Tags: image, adobe-indesign, spread, across

I'm using Indesign to create a multiple pages pdf, I have a background image across two pages, when I export the pdf the background seems not joining well over the two pages even if this image is one unique image.
[image]

Comment: Please share more details - is this even related to programming?

Comment: No is just an Indesign problem

Comment: Too vague. Share your indd + idml and pdf files. I have two suspects: (1) the not accurate layout in Indesign or (2) Acrobat failed to display correctly these areas on the screen.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b13ufbnlddy6320/AAAyiWmiPf4sTpGP9ldRyaOwa?dl=0

Comment: Alas. I can't open your INDD. Can you share an IDML?

Comment: I added it on the folder now

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming etc per the [help].

Comment: is there a forum for indesign here on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

I've made PDF from your layout (I didn't move anything, I just added the .25pt lines) and I see no problem:

[image]

[image]

It looks like the problem with the PDF viewer you're using (Acrobat?). Though my Acrobat shows no problem as well, the page edges perfect match to each other.

Try to open these pages of your PDF in Illustrator and to align them manually.

Comment: I'm usng just Indesign, not acrobat, the image is already merged like You can see on my indesogn file linked above, I can't figure out why I have this problema and you dont